# VS2012 - Button Not Posting Back

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, html, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-4.5

This has to be simple. Still, I've noticed VS2012 acting very erratic - sometimes it won't generate the designer file entries for example. Has anyone got any idea what might be going on here? I've tried adding the button both in code and by dragging it onto the design surface. I've re-created the form several times to no avail.

Here's my code:

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="submitButton" 
    OnClick="Submit_Click" Text="  Submit  "  />
```

**CODE-BEHIND:**

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        Response.Write("got to here...");
    }
}
```

**DESIGNER:**

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button Button1;
```

Comment: Open the designer and reassign the click event.

Comment: AutoEventWireup is set to true. There is no wiring up of a button handler normally in the code-behind file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove OnClick="Submit_Click", and as ASAWYER said, go to designer and double click on that button. or In backend code select General dropdown, find your button and in Declaration dropdown select click event[image]

Comment: Maybe something else in your project, in web.config preventing your postback. Remove everything from a page or create a blank one. if this wont work. Create new Project and try that.
oh and if you have master page, don't use it.

Comment: It worked on another page, but never when I create this one from scratch.

Comment: Since i haven't seen your page, you have to comment line by line or comment out everything except this button.
Also you may try to change from asp:button to asp:linkbutton ???

Comment: so asp:RequiredFieldValidator preventing postback, kicks in Validation. Try to change display to Display="Dynamic" also add this to button tag: CausesValidation="false"(if you want validation)
or CausesValidation="true" (to enable).
Also you can add ValidationSummary take a look here:  http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showasp.asp?filename=demo_validationsum

Comment: That seems to be the problem... had it set to "none"!!

Comment: Display: The display behavior for the validation control. Legal values are:
**None (the control is not displayed. Used to show the error message only in the ValidationSummary control)**
Static (the control displays an error message if validation fails. Space is reserved on the page for the message even if the input passes validation.
Dynamic (the control displays an error message if validation fails. Space is not reserved on the page for the message if the input passes validation

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_reqfieldvalidator.asp